# GROUP BY conditionally in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to figure out how I can conditionally group by in this case:

My table has the following:

```
Traveler_Code|Traveler_Name|Traveler_Gender|Traveler_state|Traveler_Class|Train_No|Flight_No|Train_apply|Flight_apply
-------------|-------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------|---------|-----------|------------
11            ABC             M             CA                 First              123   EK123        Y            Y
12            DEF             M             CA                 First         123    LH215        Y            N
13            XYZ             F             CA                 Second        456    MI890        Y            Y
14            GHI             F             CA                 Second        789    DU901        N            N
```

In the above example, I want to group travelers by Gender, state, class, train_no and flight_no. However, I need ABC and DEF in the same group because DEF has flight_apply as 'N' so I dont have to group it by Flight.

Similarly, I want XYZ and GHI in the same group because I have train_apply and flight_apply both set to 'N' for GHI. Because XYZ and GHI match when it comes to gender, state, class, I want them to be in the same group

I was looking up conditional group by, but don't quite understand how I can achieve the desired results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here are the expected results:

```
Group1  M   CA  First   123  EK123  ABC    
Group1  M   CA  First   123  NULL   DEF
Group2  F   CA  Second  456  MI890  XYZ
Group2  F   CA  Second  NULL NULL   GHI
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the desired results.

Comment: Not only what Gordon said, but also: you said XYZ and GHI must be in the same group because GHI (something about GHI). OK, so why must it be grouped with XYZ, and not with other rows? Some conditions are obviously missing from your description of the requirement.

Comment: I just tweaked my question for clarity. Please let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: This is not how `GROUP BY` works. `GROUP BY` doesn't return the rows read from the database, it produces new rows. From each group, a query with `GROUP BY` clause produces a single row. All the rows from a group must have the same values for all the columns that appear in the `SELECT` clause and are not arguments of [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035).

Comment: so how may I achieve the results? If the train_apply, flight_apply weren't there, I would probably do a distinct or group them, but with those two conditions there, I dont know how I can club them together.

Comment: What you can do to get such a result is to `SORT BY Traveler_Gender, Traveler_state, Traveler_Class, Train_No, Flight_No` and then process each row and implement the logic around the `Train_apply` and `Flight_apply` columns (should also take care when a value in one of the first four columns change because that's the moment when another group starts). You can do this either in the client code or in a stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear. For example: if GHI has both train_apply and flight_apply set to 'N', then should ALL rows that match GHI in gender, state and class be grouped together with GHI? And for DEF, ok, it has flight_apply set to 'N' - then why should ABC be grouped together with DEF (and why shouldn't other rows be grouped with DEF also)?

Comment: Yes. if GHI has both the indicators set to N, then all rows that match it on Gender, Class and State should be grouped together. And for DEF, everything that matches it on Gender, Class, State and Train No should be grouped together, irrespective of it's flight no. what the indicator does is tells us to ignore the train/flight respectively while making the grouping.

Comment: If the train apply indicator is set to 'N', then ignore train no and allow all records that match it on gender, class, state and flight no to be grouped along with it.

Comment: Why are the first two rows grouped together? They don't have the same class - one is null and the other is First.

Comment: Also, what if you had an additional row of `(15, 'JKL', 'M', 'CA', 'First', 123, 'AB837', 'Y', 'Y')`; would you expect to see the row for id = 12 match to the groups of both 11 and 15? Or should it just match to one (and if so, which one or doesn't it matter)?

Comment: The missing class was a typo. In your example, i would expect a third group to be created, because now I have to consider both train no and flight no to do the grouping and the flight no is different.

Comment: what i was hoping was that I could be able to say: GROUP BY CASE WHEN TRAIN_APPLY = 'Y' AND FLIGHT_APPLY = 'Y' THEN TRAVELER_GENDER, TRAVELER_STATE, TRAVELER_CLASS, TRAIN_NO, FLIGHT_NO CASE WHEN TRAIN_APPLY = 'N' AND FLIGHT_APPLY = 'Y' THEN.. but this wont work. I am think of other options.. may be I should group by gender, state and class first and then for the ones that say train_apply = Y and gender_apply = Y evaluate differences and take them out into another group (and so on).